# Matching and merging 2 dataframes based on partial matches of column in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 2 dataframes - call them `df1` and `df2`.

The first looks like:

`df1`

```
Name          G ID         Type         Source       Year
Washington    WTG1         Normal       Lin          2002
Washington    1            Normal       Lin          2001
Washington    4            Normal       BOX
Eddie         GT2          Normal       Lin
Mann          1            New          BOX          2018
Mann          2            Normal       BOX
Mann          SI-01        Old          Lin          2017
Mann          GGh          Old          Lin
.
.
```

The second looks like:

`df2`

```
Name          Unit ID       Year
Washington    WTG-1         2002
Washington    1             2001
Washington    4             2003
Eddie         GT02          2010
Mann          1             2018
Mann          2             2001
Mann          SI1           2017
Mann          JO            2000                       
.
.
```

As you can see `df1` has *some* of the `Year` values that `df2` has but it's random as to when it has it or not. Also, some values like `GGh` in `Mann` of `df2` has no match at all that's obvious.

The `G ID` and `Unit ID` are what I'm most interested in merging with. I need a way to make some conditions after merging on the Years (those are pretty accurate) where the `ID` values can be used to merge.

The condition would be something like Levenshtein Distance:

`if i in df1['G ID']` does not match `j in df2['Unit ID']` -> `Calculate LD` -> if `distance is close enough` then join

I know this is very pseudo code but I'm not sure how to proceed.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: CHeck with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49680416/most-likely-word-based-on-max-levenshtien-distance/49680515#49680515

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41795640/merge-pandas-data-frames-based-on-conditions

Answer (score 2):

You can try with the `.get_close_matches()` method from `difflib` like this:

```
import difflib

# make a key column to merge based on close matches
df2['Fuzzy_Key'] = df2.Unit_ID.map(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, df1.G_ID))

# since the values in our Fuzzy_Key column are lists, we have to convert them to strings
df2['Fuzzy_Key'] = df2.Fuzzy_Key.apply(lambda x: ''.join(map(str, x)))
```

**Output**

```
    Name        Unit_ID Year    Fuzzy_Key
0   Washington  WTG-1   2002    WTG1
1   Washington  1       2001    11
2   Washington  4       2003    4
3   Eddie       GT02    2010    GT2
4   Mann        1       2018    11
5   Mann        2       2001    2
6   Mann        SI1     2017    SI-01
7   Mann        JO      2000
```

After that, we can merge on the new created `Fuzzy_Key`

```
pd.merge(df2, df1[['Type', 'Source', 'Year', 'G_ID']], 
         how='left', 
         left_on=['Year', 'Fuzzy_Key'], 
         right_on=['Year', 'G_ID'])
```

**Output**

```
    Name        Unit_ID Year    Fuzzy_Key   Type    Source  G_ID
0   Washington  WTG-1   2002    WTG1        Normal  Lin     WTG1
1   Washington  1       2001    11          NaN     NaN     NaN
2   Washington  4       2003    4           NaN     NaN     NaN
3   Eddie       GT02    2010    GT2         NaN     NaN     NaN
4   Mann        1       2018    11          NaN     NaN     NaN
5   Mann        2       2001    2           NaN     NaN     NaN
6   Mann        SI1     2017    SI-01       Old     Lin     SI-01
7   Mann        JO      2000                NaN     NaN     NaN
```

**Important note**
It did not match on the keys (1 & 2001)  and (1 & 2018) because at the creation of `Fuzzy_Key` column it *close matched* to `11` and not `1` as you can see in the first output. I could not figure out why this happend, else row 1 and 4 would have matches as well.

Hope this is a start for your problem. 
Good luck!